# PHP Setting a value of a form field based on id

Tags: php, wordpress, forms

My WordPress contact form is generated like this by duplicating this line until the form is complete. The form has many fields which are determined in the WP dashboard.

```
 <input type="text" name="<?php echo "umbheadfld_".$field["field_name"]; ?>" id="<?php echo "umbheadfld_".$field["field_name"]; ?>" data-required="<?php echo $field["required"]; ?>" data-fieldtype="<?php echo $field["field_type"]; ?>">
```

However, the theme does not allow an option to set a value for the fields. I am trying to set my value as the name of the WordPress post.

Using PHP I can obtain the name of the WordPress post using this code

```
$title = get_the_title‎();
```

The first  in this post code generates a field defined as `id="umbheadfld_Subject"` as I named the field "Subject" in the WP dashboard.

I need to ammend the above code to include the value = $title if id=umbheadfld_Subject.

Any ideas?

Comment: Something like this perhaps `value="<?php echo ($field[\"field_name\"] == \"Subject\" ? $title : \"\");"` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a single line if statement using terniary operators.

```
<?php echo ($field["field_name"] == "Subject" ? "value=\"" .$title."\"" : "") ?>
```

When added to your first line:

```
 <input type="text" <?php echo ($field["field_name"] == "Subject" ? "value=\"" .$title."\"" : "") ?> name="<?php echo "umbheadfld_".$field["field_name"]; ?>" id="<?php echo "umbheadfld_".$field["field_name"]; ?>" data-required="<?php echo $field["required"]; ?>" data-fieldtype="<?php echo $field["field_type"]; ?>">
```

Comment: I have created a new variable `$refcode` which generates a random code. I would like to place this next to the subject text( i.e. Title [23456]) Unsure how to implement this?

Comment: Exactly the same way, only changing the quotes and the variable name.